# Native (non-jqueryui) way to set prompt() input field inline

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dialog

I might just be using the wrong keywords on Google, but what I have in mind is:

```
 --------------------------------
|    What is your mailbox?       |
|                                |
|    [       ]@mail.example.org  |
|                                |
|        [OK]      [Cancel]      |
 --------------------------------
```

The idea being that the input field is followed right behind by the mail server name, to help avoid instances where:

1. If I don't make it follow right behind, the user puts in the whole thing,
2. If I default it to "blah@mail.example.org" they delete the server name.

In either case, it's not too big a deal, as I will know that if the returned value does have the server, to remove it and if doesn't, I know what server it belongs to, but I think this visual aid will be a better user experience and lower the amount of validation worries I tend to get.

Comment: 'native' prompt doesn't allow this. Instead you can show a div with form on top of page, and I'd rather use jquery than invent a bicycle

Comment: @vittore I'd rather use the native prompt rather than hit it with a tank. jQuery + jqUI = tons of code

Comment: normally, i don't think of jquery/jqui as that taxing, or at the very least, it pays for itself, but in this case, I'm trying to make an iphone-driven page (it's not exclusive just to be, before you ask, it's for downloading mobile profiles). I would (and might) just say screw it and use the jq-ui, but I actually like the prompt/alerts style native to the mobile safari, so I was hoping my goal was possible to keep that native feel.

Comment: @nickf: i always try not to do any preoptimization. If tons of code is a problem - start optimizing it and write your own UI controls. If you hold small site with not that big auditory  - using jqUI is not that big deal

Comment: @Anthony: have you seen this also http://iphone.hohli.com/#?

Comment: Native `prompt` is dead. IE7 killed it. Never mind the UI limitations: for IE compatibility you can no longer use `prompt` at all anyway. You'll need a scripted in-page pop-up div. You don't need to use jQueryUI for that if you don't want to, it's not a complicated bit of script to unhide a windowshade and dialogue div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a default value in the standard Javascript prompts, but you can't do much more than that. I would just check afterwards and strip or add the server part as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the user deletes the host and doesn't specify their own host, you can assume that they intended the default host.

```
var email = prompt("What is your email address?", "@mail.example.org");
if (email.indexOf("@") === -1) {
  email += "@mail.example.org";
}
```